# Differentiate clients using boost asio

Tags: c++, udp, boost-asio

How can I differentiate clients using boost.asio and UDP, where all the boost examples use a member variable to hold one remote endpoint at a time. I need to hold a list of endpoints, and determine to which object to send the received data when it arrives. I currently have code like this

```
void Receive() {
         boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint client_endpoint;
         char data[32];
         socket_.async_receive_from(boost::asio::buffer(data, 32), client_endpoint, 
             boost::bind(&MyClass::onReceive, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
     }
```

but the `client_endpoint` will go out of scope (not be available) in the handler function, and I want to create a new `Client` object if this is the first time I am receiving from them, or update the appropriate client object if it is not.

I was thinking about holding a `std::set<boost::ip::udp::endpoint> client_sessions_;` as a member variable to my server, but `client_endpoint` is still not filled until the async call is dispatched.

How do I handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hold your endpoint in shared_ptr. Also, you have bug with asio::buffer - async_receive_from will write into stack of function, which already exited, possibly corrupting stack. Correct snippet should be something like:

```
void Receive() {
         auto client_endpoint = std::make_shared<boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint>();
         std::shared_ptr<char> data(new char[32], std::default_delete<char[]>());
         socket_.async_receive_from(boost::asio::buffer(data.get(), 32), *client_endpoint, 
             boost::bind(&MyClass::onReceive, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred, data, client_endpoint));
     }
     //...
     void MyClass::onReceive(boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred, std::shared_ptr<char> data, std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint> client_endpoint);
```

Or you can use new/delete for simplicity (less preferred)

Comment: I didn't know I could change the signature of the callback